# Monit memcached config without pidfile

Tags: memcached, centos7, monit

I have classic situation. Need to configure monit for memcached on CentOS7. The problem is, that all configs i can find in google contains this row:

```
check process memcached with pidfile /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid
```

However, There is no memcached.pid file in /var/run and no /var/run/memcached folder. I've checked /usr/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service

```
[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/memcached
ExecStart=/usr/bin/memcached -u $USER -p $PORT -m $CACHESIZE -c $MAXCONN $OPTIONS
```

So, there is no path to .pid file.
The question is can I check memcached without .pid file?
The second question - can be this .pid file in another location?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace in your monit config

```
check process memcached with pidfile /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid
```

with

```
check process memcached with match memcached
```

My config for memcached:

```
check process memcached with match memcached
    start program = "/usr/bin/systemctl start memcached"
    stop program = "/usr/bin/systemctl stop memcached"
    if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 11211 protocol MEMCACHE then restart
    if cpu > 70% for 2 cycles then alert
    if cpu > 98% for 5 cycles then restart
    if 2 restarts within 3 cycles then timeout
```

Centos 7, monit 5.14

Comment: It looks like it works. Thanks. I'll test it few hours and should accept this answer.